# Using CSS clear property correctly? Formatting is different on different browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, formatting

Apologies if this is a really simple thing, I can't seem to get it. Think I need to use *clear* but it's not working right (or I'm not using it correctly).

Am doing a pretty simple page, floating one image logo left and text on right. Then using a line break to break up image / text (you can see example here: http://transitions-london.co.uk/index.php/testimonials

It looks fine on firefox, but move to safari or chrome and the formatting is shunting some images/text to the right. Also when you scale up or down (cmd +-) the formatting changes.

I think I need to use `<div style="clear: both;">` after every `<hr />` but when I do nothing happens and the Joomla editor removes the code after saving.

Each testimonials (chunk of logo then text) is currently coded like so:

```
<div style="float: left;"><img src="images/otherlogos/nationalgrid92.png" border="1" alt="National Grid" width="92" height="92" style="padding: 20px;" /></div>
<p>"Transitions opens up an avenue for us to recruit a diverse graduate workforce. There's an option for recruiting to more experienced roles too. There's a real demand in the UK for highly skilled candidates in cables and tunnels and this presents a real alternative to find international people without the complexities around international recruitment. Some of these people may have experience in their home country that we just don't have here. If the requirements change quickly we can now respond quickly."</p>
<h5 style="text-align: right;">Sharon Goymer, Graduate Resourcing Manager, Development Programmes, National Grid</h5>
<hr />
<div style="float: left;"><img src="images/otherlogos/crossrail92.png" border="1" alt="National Grid" width="92" height="92" style="padding: 20px;" /></div>
<p>“We gained a first-class civil engineer employee as a result of Transitions.  The internship and recruitment service and candidate was above our expectations..  The refugee community offers a good untapped market.“</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<h5 style="text-align: right;">Dawn Barker, Crossrail Head of HR, Crossrail</h5>
<hr />
```

Would really appreciate the help. I know it's probably very simple.

Cheers, N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template already has a class `clr` you can use. Try adding it to your `<hr>` element like so:

```
<hr class="clr">
```

If that continues to be stripped out by the Joomla WYSIWYG Editor, then add this to one of your Joomla CSS files

```
hr {clear: both}
```

Comment: That's great. Didn't know this template had hr classes. That's done the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NicolJCraig It isn't a hr-specific class. Add class="clr" to any element and that element will get "clear: both;"